# find string that consists only of a certain set of characters

Tags: regex

I have a string and need to check whether it consists of only a certain set of characters, let's say valid characters are `abc`. So I need a regex that only matches the string if and only if the string only contains characters `a`,`b` or `c`.
So for example

- `abcaabac` should be matched
- `aaa` should be matched
- `abcxyz` should ***not*** be  matched
- `xyz` should ***not*** be matched

I think this should be possible to do with regex, but I did not succeed to construct one that does this, can you provide some help/hints? (If you have a complete solution, please tell me roughly what it does.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the characetrs `a`,`b`,`c` inside a character class and make the cahr class to repeat  one or more times by adding a `+` quantifier next to that character class.

```
^[abc]+$
```

And don't forget to add start and end anchors.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nW8vL6/2)

Comment: But I think this one does match the third example `abcxyz` doesn't it?

Comment: Ah because of `^` and `$`, so everything between beginning and end must consitst of `[abc]+`, right? Now I finally understand the importance of `^` and `$`, thank you very much!